# enter an equation in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm a beginner using Jupyter notebook (python) and they've asked me to type the attached equation in a markdown cell using LaTEX and then in a code cell to do operations with it. I have no idea of how to type the complex symbols it has. [image of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zKWA.png)

I tried to write it in the platform. I use a MacBook and don't know where many of the symbols the equation has are located/how to type them

Comment: Create a markdown cell and write equations with [markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions).

Comment: See [link](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/content/math.html)

Comment: As for coding that in a cell and doing operations with it, I suspect you are looking for sympy. See [here](https://github.com/josephcslater/Introduction_to_Python/blob/master/SymPy_Examples.ipynb), [here](https://github.com/josephcslater/Introduction_to_Python/blob/master/Calc_Review.ipynb), and the resources listed [here & in the next reply below that](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/in-line-latex-in-notebooks/15709/2?u=fomightez). In particular, ['Maths Overview' by Tony Hirst (psychemedia
)](https://opencomputinglab.github.io/SubjectMatterNotebooks/maths/overview.html).

Comment: <continued> There is  [latex2sympy2](https://github.com/OrangeX4/latex2sympy) - "latex2sympy2 parses LaTeX math expressions and converts it into the equivalent SymPy form. " (On the flip side is [latexify_py](https://github.com/google/latexify_py). [Example](https://khuyentran1401.github.io/Efficient_Python_tricks_and_tools_for_data_scientists/Chapter6/better_outputs.html#latexify-py-generates-a-latex-math-description-from-a-python-function).) And note you can  play around with SymPy directly in your browser, without installing anything [here](https://sympy.org/en/shell.html).